# what is the difference between these two projects, ASP.NET MVC2 web application and ASP.NET MVC2 Empty Web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

what is the difference between these two projects, ASP.NET MVC2 web application and ASP.NET MVC2 Empty Web application?

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET MVC Internet Web Application adds the Admin controller allowing you to register users which may authenticate on the site using the membership provider. It also contains the corresponding views. The empty project generates no controllers and views.

Also I guess that you are talking about ASP.NET MVC 3, as the default project template in ASP.NET MVC 2 doesn't have this distinction => it systematically creates the Admin controller.